# Cannot upload large csv files

Tags: php, csv

I wrote a php script to extract data from a csv script and insert it into an mysql database. It does the job but does not extract data and insert into database for large csv files.(I tried extracting and inserting from a csv file with 40,000 rows. Did not work but worked when i tested it out with a far smaller (60 rows) size csv file). I get no error message. It just doesn't work. During debugging i realised even echoing a string after selecting a large csv file and clicking my upload button does not work. I've searched and tried all the possible configurations in php.ini as well as LimitRequestBody for apache config as well as setting configs directly in my code to no success. Some help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below.

```
    <?php

include ("connection.php");


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $sql10 = "insert into upload (filename) values ('$file_name')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql10)){
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " .$last_id;
    } 
    //mysqli_close($conn);
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    //ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== false)
    {
        if ($c > 0) {

            $event_id = $filesop[0];
            $conf_session_id = $filesop[1];
            $service_provider_id = $filesop[2];
            $service_provider_id2 = $filesop[3];
            $billed_flag = $filesop[4];
            $offering_id = $filesop[5];
            $time_start = $filesop[6];
            $time_ended = $filesop[7];
            $duration = $filesop[8];
            $orig_calling_code = $filesop[9];
            $orig_area_code = $filesop[10];
            $termination_reason = $filesop[11];
            $rtp_encoding = $filesop[12];
            $rtp_clock_rate = $filesop[13];
            $sip_from = $filesop[14];
            $sip_to = $filesop[15];
            $sip_call_id = $filesop[16];
            $orig_nbr = $filesop[17];
            $dest_nbr = $filesop[18];
            $popd_account_number = $filesop[19];
            $intl_dest_flag = $filesop[20];
            $sip_status = $filesop[21];
            $gw_ip_ingress = $filesop[22];
            $gw_port_egress = $filesop[23];
            $phone_number = $filesop[24];
            $orig_flag = $filesop[25];
            $subscriber_sip_caller_id = $filesop[26];
            $orig_route_type = $filesop[27];
            $term_route_type = $filesop[28];
            $call_type = $filesop[29];
            $mny_BasePrice = $filesop[30];
            $call_cost = $filesop[31];
            $uploadID = $last_id;


            $sql11 = "insert into cdr (event_id, conf_session_id, service_provider_id, service_provider_id2, billed_flag, offering_id, time_start, time_ended, duration, orig_calling_code, orig_area_code, termination_reason, rtp_encoding, rtp_clock_rate, sip_from, sip_to, sip_call_id, orig_nbr, dest_nbr, popd_account_number, intl_dest_flag, sip_status, gw_ip_ingress, gw_port_egress, phone_number, orig_flag, subscriber_sip_caller_id, orig_route_type, term_route_type, call_type, mny_BasePrice, call_cost, uploadID, date_uploaded) values ('$event_id', '$conf_session_id', '$service_provider_id', '$service_provider_id2', '$billed_flag', '$offering_id', '$time_start', '$time_ended', '$duration', '$orig_calling_code', '$orig_area_code', '$termination_reason', '$rtp_encoding', '$rtp_clock_rate', '$sip_from', '$sip_to', '$sip_call_id', '$orig_nbr', '$dest_nbr', '$popd_account_number', '$intl_dest_flag', '$sip_status', '$gw_ip_ingress', '$gw_port_egress', '$phone_number', '$orig_flag', '$subscriber_sip_caller_id', '$orig_route_type', '$term_route_type', '$call_type', '$mny_BasePrice', '$call_cost', '$uploadID', CURRENT_DATE)";



            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql11)){
                // $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
            // echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " .$last_id;
                $updatequery = "UPDATE cdr JOIN client ON cdr.orig_nbr = client.phonenumber SET cdr.clientname = client.clientname";
                mysqli_query($conn, $updatequery);
            } else{
                echo "error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
            }


        }
        $c++;


    }






    fclose($handle) ;

}
```

?>

Comment: Add this to the top of your script: `set_time_limit(0);`. If a script takes to long to finish, it'll automaticly cut off. This will prevent that. Also, take a look at your php.ini file. You might want to increase the settings of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to allow for large file uploads.

Comment: @icecub didn't work. also been increasing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings constantly but i still get the same problem

Comment: Alright, remove the `set_time_limit(0);` and try this at the top of your code: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors' 1);`. Then run the file and wait untill it just stops. It should give some usefull information about what's going on now.

Comment: @icecub still nothing displays. It just stops running. :(